# tsql - concatenate a group of strings and then update a record with that resulting string

Tags: t-sql, concatenation, common-table-expression

I have three tables: 1. a work order operations table that has a field that points to a machine group that the operation is assigned to. 2. Machine Group table 3. Machine group members table

In the operations table:
WorkOrderNumber, OperationNumber, MachineGroupName, MaterialSize, ListofWorkCenters

In the MachineGroup Table:
MachineGroupName

In the MachineGroupMembers Table:
MachineGroupName, WorkCenterName, SizeCapacity

I need to build a list of WorkCenterNames where the operations.materialsize <= MachineGroupMembers.SizeCapacity and then update the operations.ListofWorkCenters with the list.

Example:
Operations.MaterialSize = 36

MachineGroupMembers.Name MachineGroupMembers.SizeCapacity
200A                     48
200B                     24
200C                     48
200D                     36
200E                     30

Result: Operations.ListofWorkCenters = 200A|200C|200D

I assume that using CTE is the way to get this but am having trouble coming up with the code.  Any ideas on this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: *updateable CTE* might point you in the right direction... If you want help please provide a reduced test scenarion with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are looking for a way to do this as a set operation but, if I am following you correctly, here is one (not so pretty) way to get this done. Took some liberties with you table structures of course.

```
declare @MachineGroupMembers table (Name VARCHAR(100), SizeCapacity INT)
declare @Operations table (OperationNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1), MaterialSize INT, ListofWorkCenters VARCHAR(500))
declare @ListofWorkCenters VARCHAR(500) = '', @row INT = 1, @cnt INT

insert @Operations 
select 36, ''
union ALL
select 40, ''

set @cnt = (select count(*) from @Operations)

insert @MachineGroupMembers
select '200A', 48
union ALL
select '200B', 24
union ALL
select '200C', 48
union ALL
select '200D', 36
union ALL
select '200E', 30

while @row <= @cnt
    begin

        SELECT @ListofWorkCenters = @ListofWorkCenters + Name + '|'
        FROM @MachineGroupMembers MGM
        WHERE MGM.SizeCapacity >= (SELECT MaterialSize FROM @Operations WHERE OperationNumber = @row)

        update @Operations
        set ListofWorkCenters = LEFT(@ListofWorkCenters, LEN(@ListofWorkCenters)-1)
        WHERE OperationNumber = @row

        SET @row += 1
        SET @ListofWorkCenters = ''
    end

select * from @Operations
```

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly and it certainly looks like you have provided a solution to accomplish the need.  I wonder, though, is this more expensive that using a CTE solution?  Thank you for your input on this!